# Gulp SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: node.js, gulp-sass

```
    "use strict";

const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpSass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('style', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(gulpSass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/styles'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('style'));
```

**Ошибка с консоли**

```
$ node ./node_modules/.bin/gulp
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\less28\node_modules\.bin\gulp:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47←[39m
```

Comment: Запускать bash-скрипт нодой под виндой это оригинально.

Comment: Попробуйте `npx gulp`